# slick slider issue in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, image

i want to click on thumbnail slicker images(only one image) and it should open on gallery with slider(all remaining images should display on slide ).

Thumbnail slider code.

```
<img ng-repeat="item in vm.galleryItems.rows"
                 ng-src="http://192.168.1.133:8081/uploads/property/thumbnails/{{item.gallery}}" class="galleryItem"
                 ng-click="vm.setImage(item.gallery)>
```

click function in controller as

```
vm.setImage = function ( url ) {
        vm.displayImage = url;


    }
```

and my gallery slider will only one image code is here

```
<slick class="slider top-slider"  ng-click="maimslide($index)" infinite="false"  
                       slides-to-show="1" 
                       settings="slickConfig" ng-if="slickConfig1Loaded" >
                      <div class="slick-item"/>
<img   ng-src="http://192.168.1.133:8081/uploads/property/{{vm.displayImage1}}" class=""> 
</slick>
```

How i can dispaly all images of Thumbnail in gallery and also slicker to be work